# Adding constraint to bottom anchor is adding to constraint to superview bottom

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I'm trying to add constraints to UIImageview to be leading, trailing, top and bottom to the safe area layout guide like this :

[image: safe area constraints]

```
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        [[self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bgImageView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor] setActive:true];
        [[self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bgImageView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor] setActive:true];
        [[self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bgImageView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor] setActive:true];
        [[self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bgImageView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor] setActive:true];
    }
```

but, the actual result is :

[image]

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could using

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        bgImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        bgImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        bgImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        bgImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ])
```